# is there a way to test watchPosition(googlemaps) without move my self from my chair

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework

i am implementing a app in which i have to track my position and move the map accordingly the updated position. i dont wont to go outside to test every time i change something while i make it work. Any ideas?

```
       let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
        watch.subscribe((data) => {


        let latlng: LatLng = new LatLng(data.coords.latitude, data.coords.longitude);

        // create CameraPosition
        let positionActual: CameraPosition = {
            target: latlng,
            zoom: 19,
            tilt: 30
        };
        this.currentMap.moveCamera(positionActual);

    });
```

Comment: Why not simply change `data.coords.latitude, data.coords.longitude` for whatever you see fit?

Comment: Because i need to see in real time the camera focus positioned in the latlng

Comment: I don't get what you want to do. I think you should rewrite your question to be a lot more descriptive on your needs.